# How to disable interrupt in Linux

Tags: arm, interrupt

I am using mini2440 arm board, and GPIO to control the hardware connected with the GPIO. I am using BSP that ships with the cd of the board. I have only enabled functionality which I will need for running the hardware.

I have disabled audio, Ethernet and unnecessary stuff in kernel, so that it don;t cause interrupt hence CPU attention. But the problem is sometimes some interrupt occur on the GPIO and hardware do malfunction. I know I can see all interrupt via cat /proc/interrupt, but how should i know which interrupt occur on GPIO from which device?

I am running my application with highest nice priority (-20), but still sometime external interrupt occur.

When i send data on GPIO, only TimerTick  of s3c2440 do interrupt, but that's fine, it is require, but not other. Please tell me how to find which interrupt occur (I know I can check it via cat /proc/interrupt) and how to disable (Disable interrupt on ethernet via ifconfig eth0 down) interrupt from kernel? Need some expert solution, I have tried the solution getting help from people but need some expert solution.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling devices in the kernel has no real efect on interrupts (generated by the *hardware*), it just affects how *software* handles them. If the device isn't present, no interrupts get generated. And Linux was written by absolute performance freaks, barring misbehaving hardware the interrupt handling is nearly as good/fast as it could be.

What exactly are you trying to do? Are you *sure* you aren't trying to get performance that your machine just can't deliver?

Comment: The device is not present, it software generate the interrupt, The only interrupt which is getting increment is  'S2c2440 Timer Tick' which is correct as per the processor to operate GPIO.  I am trying to get the maximum performance delivered by my system and I can get it, but some times it misbehave from the system side. I am not trying to get excess performance by the machine than it gives.